# Python - How to send data from a certain point (resume download)

Tags: python, sockets, fileserver

I'm trying to make a file server in Python using only sockets. What would be a way I could go about skipping reading the first "x" amount of bytes in a file then sending it? I'm pretty good at sockets but not at reading files so if anyone could help it would be great!

Edit: No protocol. Just a Python server on a random port. Client and server will both be custom.

Comment: Details on the protocol? HTTP? FTP?

Comment: Use the file's `.seek()` method to skip over bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use the `.seek()` method to skip the data and then start reading from there and send the rest of the data as needed. Thanks @pm-2ring for showing me this method.